# Finding Maximum Height Path in Binary Tree in C++

Tags: c++, tree

I need to take inputs from a user to fill the Tree, and then find the maximum height and the directions to get it. (L - left and R - right)
For example, user inputs: 50 25 75 15 40 60 30 55 56 57
The output should be HRLLRR but I've got HRRRR

Or another example when of input: 50 25 75 15 40 60 100
Output must be HRR but I've got HRRR

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Tree {
private : 
    T info;
    Tree* left;
    Tree* right;
public : 
    Tree() {
        info = NULL;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
    Tree* insert(Tree<T>* head,T value);
    void InOrder(Tree* head);
    void findMaxPath(Tree<T>*);
    int findMax(Tree<T>*);
};

    string path="H";

int main() {
    Tree<int>* head = NULL; 
    char ch;
    int info; 
    do  {
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch) {
        case 'i':
            cin >> info;
            head = head->insert(head, info);
            break;
        case 'p':
            head->InOrder(head);
            cout << endl;
            break;
        case 'm': 
            head->findMaxPath(head);
            cout << path << endl;
            break;
        }
    }while (ch != 'e');
}

template <typename T>
Tree<T>* Tree<T>::insert(Tree<T>* head,T value) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = new Tree<T>();
        head->info = value;
        return head;
    }
    if (head->info > value) {
        head->left = insert(head->left, value);
    }
    else
        head->right = insert(head->right, value);

    return head;
}
template <typename T>
void Tree<T>::InOrder(Tree<T>* head) {
    if (head != NULL) {
        InOrder(head->left);
        cout << head->info << " ";
        InOrder(head->right);
    }
}
template <typename T>
void Tree<T>::findMaxPath(Tree<T>* head){
    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "Empty" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else findMax(head);
}
template <typename T>
int Tree<T>::findMax(Tree<T>* head){
    if (head==NULL){
        cout << path << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else{  
        int leftMax, rightMax; 
        int max = head->info;  
        if(head->left != NULL){  
            leftMax = findMax(head->left);  
            if(leftMax > max){
            max = leftMax;  
            path+="L";
            }
        }  
        if(head->right != NULL){  
          rightMax = findMax(head->right);
          if(rightMax > max){
            max = rightMax;  
            path+="R";
            }
        }  
    return max;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: "Binary Tree" just means that each node can't have more than two children. It doesn't say anything about the rules of how you're building said tree. So a valid Binary Tree with inputs `50 25 75 15 40` could just make the first the root and the next four right children to end with a height of 5. Without knowing how you WANT your tree to look, it's impossible to say whether what you have is wrong.

Comment: I would recommend stepping through your code with a debugger first to understand what your code is doing vs what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: @scohe001 The `insert` function is provided, so I think that answers your question.

Comment: You may want to get the tree working first without being a template.  You can always convert to a template after you get the tree working.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews the requirement for this particular task is to use a template

Comment: @cigien since the code is clearly failing (hence the question), we have no guarantee that the `insert()` function is correct or doing what OP thinks/wants it to do. If you want to try to puzzle out what's right and what's wrong with the code without a starting idea of what's *supposed* to be happening, be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions: You insert the given sequence of nodes one by one into a binary search tree.

The problem is in your `findMax()` function. Notice that you append the 'L' or 'R' to the `path` variable even when you are not traversing the "max" region.

For the second input (50 25 75 15 40 60 100), the appends are done in the order: by 25 (for 40), by 75 (for 100), by 50 (for 75). Hence you get one extra 'R' when you function recurses the left subtree of the root (by 25).

Also, you set your `max` variable to the value of the node and you are taking the greater value children, its not the maximum height children as stated in the question.